# How can I sign message using an Ethereum private key in Python?

Tags: python, cryptography, ethereum

On JS I can use ethers to sign message and get v r s

```
const { utils } = require("ethers");

// for example types = [address, uint256], params = [0x4F..., 100], privateKey=0x45..
const getSignString = (types=undefined, params=undefined, privateKey=undefined) => {
    const digest = utils.keccak256(utils.solidityPack(types, params));
    return new utils.SigningKey(privateKey).signDigest(digest);
  };

// return obj.r, obj.v, obj.s ...
```

How can i do this on Python?

---

Find answer  for my question

```
def custom_sign_message(types: List, params: List, private_key: str) -> SignMessage:
    """
    Sign message
    types: types of data, for example ["address", "uint256", ...]
    params: params to sign. len(types) == len(params)
    private key: customer private key
    return signed message, containing v, r, s for tests
    """
    signature = Web3.toHex(Web3.soliditySha3(types, params))
    message = encode_defunct(hexstr=signature)
    signed_message = w3.eth.account.sign_message(message, private_key)
    res = eth_account.account.Account.signHash(message.body, private_key)
    return SignMessage(
        v=res.v,
        r=Web3.toHex(res.r),
        s=Web3.toHex(res.s),
        message_hash=signed_message.messageHash,
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [eth_account sign_message](https://eth-account.readthedocs.io/en/stable/eth_account.html#eth_account.account.Account.sign_message) method.

To pack the parameters to binary you can use [eth-abi package](https://eth-abi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/encoding.html).

Comment: Thx, but he problem lies that when using the current methods to sign messages, it adds in the prefix before signing it.

Account.sign_message(msghash, key[0])

Comment: https://eth-account.readthedocs.io/en/stable/eth_account.html#eth_account.account.Account.sign_message

Comment: Look eth-account source code, copy the relevant function and remove the part where it adds the prefix if this is an issue.